# Selecting text in MacVim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, macvim, textselection

One of the many nice features of MacVim is that after enabling this option:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
    let macvim_hig_shift_movement = 1
endif
```

it lets you to select text using Shift, Option and Arrows.

However, is it possible to modify the selecting behavior? For now, if moving forward, it mimics Vim's `vw`, while I'd prefer it to be something like `ve` (i.e., do not select a space after a word). Also, `set selection = exclusive` is good but not enough.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you need that? Isn't the visual mode doing just that?

Comment: 'Cause I'm more used to Shift-Arrows than to the Visual mode :).

Comment: So, may I assume, there's no answer?